Is the hydrogen atom heavier or lighter than the sum of individual particles?
I found a question in one of the exams (JAM-2005). I have attached the image to the question and related links. Wherever I found, the correct answer for the question is given as option (c). But isn't it wrong, because in that way the mass of hydrogen atom will be more than the sum of the mass of proton and electron. Therefore, the correct option should be option (b)

Edit: It has been notified me that my question is similar to some other question posted here but my concern is about verifying the facts, i.e. the mass of proton, electron and hydrogen atom so that I can verify the answer given on various websites and conclude whether it is wrong or not. The answer that is provided in the other question does not provide any link to verify the values and hence the correct answer to my posted question.

This is what happens when somebody prepares questions and solutions for students and nobody else reviews them.

Yes, it has wrongly formulated options. c) is very wrong, a), b) are close to correct, and d) is correct, because ground state energy isn't exactly -13.6 eV.

@JánLalinský Pun intended?

This question is similar to: Does the mass of an electron change with its "energy state"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@my2cts Where do you see pun?

@JánLalinský Well, you must be joking that d) is correct. In my understanding, the notation 13.6 eV includes the experimental value of 13.598434599702 eV given by NIST. This make b) the correct answer.

@my2cts d) is the only correct option from the four options given, because ground state energy is not exactly $13.6$eV and thus b) is not exactly true. 13.6 eV does not include 13.598434599702 eV, these are different numbers, and this second number isn't exactly true magnitude of energy of ground state either. The question suggests $K=-13.6$eV, so assuming that, it follows b) is correct, but that suggestion is not exactly correct. It is a badly formulated question (mainly the "exactly true" part).

@JánLalinský This is pedantic, with all due respect. Also x=13.6 can be read as 13.55$\leq$x$\lt$13.65.

@my2cts Yes. My pedantry here was induced by the badly formulated question.
